Why does the proposed Lunar Crater Radio Telescope suggest an optimal latitude of 20 degrees North?
In the proposal for NASA's Lunar Crater Radio Telescope, it claims that one of the key requirements is a "location on farside near ≈ 20°N and 180° ±45°E to avoid Earth-based radio interference near the lunar limbs".
I understand the concept of using the Moon as a radio shield to block out signals from Earth, but why is the optimal latitude at 20 degrees North and not the more intuitive 0 degrees North?

According to the proposal (p. 3-4), the main reason for the location at 20°N is to avoid the strong signals given off by the Milky Way itself.

Galactic Foreground Noise — One of the main challenges in collecting data at such low frequencies is the synchrotron radiation from our own Milky Way galaxy, referred to as the Galactic foreground.


Fig. 8 shows the Galactic foreground signal in the Galactic reference frame. The lines show the region of the sky that LCRT would see, with appropriate beam-width and no steering, if it were located at different latitudes on the Moon. We would like to avoid the strong signals from the center of the Milky Way Galaxy, while also covering different sections of the sky. We hence choose to select lunar craters near 20°N latitude.



Figure 8: Galactic foreground as a function of Lunar latitude,
with known Exoplanets

The track corresponding to an observation area at 20°N (third from left) is the most-equatorial track that avoids the bright areas near the center of the foreground noise. Placing the telescope further north would have less of an impact on the foreground noise, while reducing the effectiveness of the Moon's attenuation of Earthly signals.

Very interesting! I guess the receiver position is fixed, so the actual width of the lines in Figure 8 would range from 0.7 to 7 degrees for 10 to 100 meter wavelengths. Fyi you may also be able to add an answer to Is there an advantage to the equatorial region of the far side of the moon for a radio telescope or would any crater on the far side work? in Astronomy SE.
